# WebGL differs from OpenGL preprocessor on same graphics stack

Tags: opengl-es, preprocessor, glsl, webgl

I just come upon an interesting effect by Chrome's use of the GLSL compiler. The statement

```
#define addf(index) if(weights[i+index]>0.) r+=weights[i+index]*f##index(p);
```

does not compile stating

```
preprocessor command must not be preceded by any other statement in that line
```

It seems that the `##` syntax is unsupported.
However, on the same platform (eg. Linux 64bit, Nvidia GPU) the same shader compiles and runs fine. Why this? I thought the shader compiler is part of the GPUs driver stack and would be used in both cases. So why this different experience?

Comment: Since you've learned that it's actually following the standard correctly, it would be good to correct the mistaken claim above that this is a bug in Chrome's GLSL compiler. Aside from that, I would upvote this question.

Comment: That is misunderstood, I don't assume that there is a bug 'in' Chrome's GLSL compiler as I thought there only is one compiler inside the GPU vendors driver stack. However it seems there are more than one (or more profiles, so to say), but maybe those are still in the vendor stack. The problem I was facing is no WebGL bug at all, as the `##` operator is clearly forbidden by WebGL's specification. However I am still wondering how this different behaveour occurs, as  I am still not sure how Chrome does achieves this error occur while other GL apps don't trigger it.

Comment: OK, I don't understand how "a bug in the WebGL GLSL compiler used by Chrome" doesn't mean "a bug 'in' Chrome's GLSL compiler." Maybe the contrast is in the question of whether the compiler is Chrome's or not? But anyway you've removed the wording ... thanks. +1

Comment: All WebGL implementations, (Opera, WebKit, Firefox, Chrome) are required to enforce these restrictions. To do that they validate GLSL shaders before passing them to the GPU driver. WebKit, Firefox and Chrome all use the same validator. Opera uses its own. There are WebGL Conformance Tests that test that these validators enforce these restrictions. The reason they are enforced so to try as much as possible to prevent shaders from working on one driver or device and not another.

Comment: Ok. That means that Chrome is maybe using the normal OpenGL stack on my system (not OpenGL ES as I wondered about if desktop drivers provide that) but does prechecks that I attributed to OpenGL driver itself. Well, they came out of the officially OpenGL shader log at last...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebGL implementations needs to conform the WebGL specifications. Many restrictions are needed for security issues. The `##` issue is not, but anyway not correct by the WebGL specs.

To conform, they can either use a graphics stack that fully conform (for example by providing a wrapper to an unextended OpenGL ES profile if the driver exhibits those) or by prechecking the GLSL shader code and WebGL state itself to ensure conformity before passing the comamnds to some full OpenGL implementation.

So the WebGL behaviour may differ from the native OpenGL behaviour on the same machine.

Comment: This actually merges Tobias Schlegel's answer and gman's comment. Thank you both!

Answer (score 11):

Actually WebGL is also quoted as "OpenGL ES 2.0 for the Web", so there are some differences to OpenGL.

The WebGL spec ( https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/1.0/ ) tells us:
"A WebGL implementation must only accept shaders which conform to The OpenGL ES Shading Language, Version 1.00."

Looking into the GLSL ES 1.0 spec ( https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf ) I found:

Section 3.4 defines the preprocessor and also states "There are no number sign based operators (no #, #@, ##, etc.), nor is there a sizeof operator."

So whatever the browser's implementation does internally, it follows the standard :)

Comment: 'it follows the standard'.. I agree. Still strange how it does... And sad these operators are excluded. The `##` operator in particular is easy to implement but hard to work around if not available.

Comment: Maybe the answer is then, that the Nvidia drivers actually implement OpenGL ES too even on desktop platforms, and Chrome uses the real OpenGL ES stack if available?

Answer (score 1):

That's because on Windows, Chrome does not use the OpenGL driver by default. It uses Direct3D, and the translation from OpenGL to Direct3D is done by the [ANGLE](http://code.google.com/p/angleproject/) project.

ANGLE has its own shader validator and preprocessor. And hence you can see differences between Windows and other operating systems even though you're using the same hardware. ANGLE was created because on Windows the Direct3D support is typically much better than the OpenGL support, and because it allows more control over the implementation and its conformance.

Comment: That may explain such experiences on Windows platform, but I first faced this effect on a fully OpenGL capable Linux machine.